# Tensorflow jobs causing high disk load on the Root Filesystem

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

When running training using Tensorflow, the root filesytem, which is on two SSDs, is seeing extremely high disk utilization, with a wait as high as 39min. Trying to figure out what is causing it.

```
11:42:43 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
11:42:45 PM       sda      2.00      0.00   4096.00   2048.00    143.11  57598.00    500.00    100.00
11:42:45 PM       md0      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
11:42:45 PM       sdb      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
11:42:45 PM       sdc      2.00      0.00   4096.00   2048.00    143.10  57594.00    500.00    100.00
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more about what your training program is doing? For example, how often are you writing checkpoints? Or is it possible that you are running out of memory and the disk load is a result of paging?

Comment: My code is loading large files from the hard drive with a few parallel processes and putting them in the shared memory. Another process is taking these data and training a convolutional network using them. I'm writing the checkpoints once every couple of hours. Memory doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: also looking at open file handles, there is a single 2.4GB file that is getting created and deleted

Comment: python      4113                       user  DEL       REG              252,0                 914004 /tmp/pymp-rlql6km8/pym-4113-iab_xhbf
python      4113                       user  30u      REG              252,0 2496000000      914004 /tmp/pymp-rlql6km8/pym-4113-iab_xhbf (deleted)
python      4113                       user  31u      REG              252,0 2496000000      914004 /tmp/pymp-rlql6km8/pym-4113-iab_xhbf (deleted)
python      4113   4188                user DEL       REG              252,0                 9